# Cannot reinstall Composer on WAMP server

Tags: windows, composer-php, wampserver

I have uninstalled Composer using the Windows uninstaller (I'm on Windows 8) and now when I run the Composer installer I get:

> Composer is already installed in the following directory:
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12
>
> You must remove it first, if you want to continue this installation.

Since obviously Windows did not completely remove it can anybody with more skills than me give me a tip on how to fix?

Comment: Well I would start by looking in the `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12` folder for anything that does not normally exists and looks like a piece of Composer. Then remove it, put it somewhere safe incase its actually a part of PHP so you can put it back if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the path C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12 from your Environment variable, named Path in the System properties.